# Новичок в бутстрапе начал электронно изучать язык

Tags: bootstrap

Скачал бутстрап и тут же сказали удалить некоторые файлы и оставить только бутстрап мини. можно не удалять а то сказали оставить минифицированную версию и есть отличие в работе

Comment: Какой язык????? Если вы имеете ввиду Bootstrap, так это не язык программирования. Взялись учить отлично, но называйте тогда сразу все своими именами

Comment: Отличий в работе нету, если это был вопрос. Минификация никак не влияет на код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам ничего и не надо удалять.

Просто начните с готового шаблона практиковаться.

Скопируйте один из этих кодов на свою страницу.

[4.1 версия](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

[3.3 версия](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template)

А остальное уже через пару дней поймете.